# AWS Machine Learning issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter, machine-learning

I use AWS Machine Learning to predict if a tweet message is positive or negative.
I have a CSV file with about 1000 tweets (2 columns "message" TEXT and "is_postive" BINARY).
If the message contains some words that I've defined by my side, "is_positive" is set to 0 (else 1)

My issue is that evaluations always return 1 (even if I try a message with a "bad" word).

How can I have more relevant results?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your datasource and select your LM model. Clicking on the attributes will give you an idea of how "statistically relevant" the columns in your teaching data are.  Your result is most probably due to your teaching data.  Since the entire tweet message is in one column, the model is most likely looking for a correlation on all words in the sample tweets. A better model may be to use a "sentiment" library of which there are publicly available versions which would shift your model to look at each word in the tweet vs. the tweet as a whole as yours currently is.